# Can't open deepin control-center on i3

Tags: i3, startx, deepin

I can't open deepin control-center on i3wm on arch linux. When I try to execute `dde-control-center`, I get the following error:

```
"dtkwidget2" can not find qm files
load translate "/usr/share/dde-control-center/translations/dde-control-center_en_US"
2018-11-29, 22:32:18.801 [Debug  ] [                                                         
0] QVariant DBusExtendedAbstractInterface::internalPropGet(const char*, void*) "This 
Extended DBus interface is not valid yet."
2018-11-29, 22:32:18.845 [Warning] [                                                         
0] QLayout: Attempting to add QLayout "" to MainWidget "", which already has a layout
```

I have just recently moved to arch so I'm not too familiar with it yet, but in Ubuntu I could work around this using `XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity; unity-control-center`, is there a similar solution for deepin? I don't want to move to a DE entirely to use the control center.

Note: I'm using i3wm with startx, no DM.

Comment: `I don't want to move to a DE entirely to use the control center` - Isn't the Deepin Control Center meant for the Deepin Desktop (DDE- Deepin Desktop Environment)? Is it possible or meanful to have the CC without DDE? On Deepin Linux the command to launch it is `dbus-send --print-reply --dest=com.deepin.dde.ControlCenter /com/deepin/dde/ControlCenter com.deepin.dde.ControlCenter.Show` - or `dbus-send --print-reply --dest=com.deepin.dde.ControlCenter /com/deepin/dde/ControlCenter com.deepin.dde.ControlCenter.Toggle` to toggle.